# Edit form for List<String> MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates

I'm trying to create a page to edit 'Person', however I'm having trouble with how to edit a List object (and by edit, I mean how to dynamically add an email to the list). Researching online as well as on stackoverflow has led me to EditorTemplates and then dynamically adding items with ajax. However, I've missed a connection somewhere. Either I create a unbound empty textbox for the new email, or get get an null reference error.

Model:

```
[DynamoDBTable("people")]
public class Person
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    [DynamoDBProperty(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [DynamoDBRangeKey]
    [DynamoDBProperty(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty(AttributeName = "emails")]
    public List<string> Emails{ get; set; }

    public Person()
    {

    }
}
```

View:

```
<div id="emails" class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Emails)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Emails, new { @class = "form-control"})
    </div>
    <button id="addEmail">Add</button>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#addEmail").on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: '/controller/newEmail'
            }).success(function (partialView) {
                $('#emails').append(partialView);
            });
        });
</script>
```

EditorTemplate - Person:

```
@model Models.Person

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Emails.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Emails)

}
```

EditorTemplate - String:

```
@model string

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model)
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult newEmail()
{
    var emails = new Person().Emails;

    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/string.cshtml", emails);
}
```

Comment: You do not need ajax. You just need to append a new input - `<input type="text" name="Emails" />` to the DOM using javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Person.Emails` object is null and hasn't been initialized

```
public ActionResult newEmail()
{
    var emails = new Person().Emails;

    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/string.cshtml", emails);
}
```

Change it to:

```
public ActionResult newEmail()
{
    var emails = new Person().Emails = new List<string>();

    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/string.cshtml", emails);
}
```